# rails2 to rails3 routing problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

On my old application(rails 2.3) I had:

```
myapp::Application.routes.draw do |map| 
map.resources :posts, :has_many => :comments
```

now in my rails3 app I removed the |map| syntax
and I have

```
myapp::Application.routes.draw do 
resources :posts, :has_many => :comments
```

This gives me the following error:
No route matches {:controller=>"comments", :post_id=>#

and this is the form I'm trying to submit:
Extracted source (around line #11):

```
11: <% form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>
```

That was working fine on rails 2 but when I'm trying to remove the |map| syntax I'm getting an error. does anyone knows how to fix that problem ?

Thnak you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new syntax is:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

From official [Ruby on Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).